How to share a static website via sharepoint?
I'd like to share a static website through sharepoint in my organization. Best case would be if it would also be viewable from MS teams.How can I do that?
A minimalistic example for this question would be a structure like this:
/
 - index.html
 - script.js
 - a_pdf_file_the_index_is_linking_to.pdf
 - style.css

Ultimately I'd like to share a static react site.
I'd like to emphasize: this is supposed to be an organization-private share. Only people with access to the sharepoint folder that hosts  the site should actually be able to open it.
I tried the Website tab in a team, but that will only work for a single html files with no links allowed.
